# Cannot retrieve data from database to drop down list

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter and I'm having a problem in retrieving data from database to drop down list. Can anyone help me with this?

My View:

```
      <?php echo form_open('form/myform'); ?>

<select id="addother" >

    <option value="none" selected="selected"> ------Select School------ </option>

        <?php foreach($groups as $row) { 

         echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';

        } ?>

  </select>

<div id="addother">
  <?php  echo form_input(array('id'=>'addother_input', 'name'=>'school', 'placeholder'=>'Enter name of school...')); ?>
  <input type="submit" id="add" name="submit" value="+" />
</div>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

My Controller:

```
    function myform(){
    $data['title'] = "myform";

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->load->model('school_model');

    if($this->input->post()){

        $sdata['school'] = $this->input->post('school');

        $this->school_model->addItem($sdata);

    }

    $data['groups'] = $this->school_model->getAll();

    $this->load->view('myform', $data);

}
```

My Model:

```
 function getAll() {

$query = $this->db->get('tblschool');

 return $query->result();

}


function addItem($sdata){

   return $this->db->insert('tblschool', $sdata);

}
```

I can't retrieve data from database into the drop down list. I would really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: From where do you call the `drop` function?

Comment: Is the data getting inserted to the database because you have not given name attribute to select tag?

Comment: What is the problem exactly ? The dropdown not have options ? The dropdown value is not sending to the server at submit ?

Comment: I can already add some data into the database. My problem is that it won't retrieve the data from the database into the drop down list. My drop down list won't display the data that I added into the database.

Comment: There is an input box and submit button below the drop down list where I'm adding some data into the database.

Comment: Try `print_r($groups);`

Comment: @Angelo you need to call the drop function from controller. If you have done that then can you please edit your question - so it becomes clear to us?

Comment: I've edited my controller and it finally adds some rows in the drop down list, but it only adds blank rows. The data that I've added into the database still won't appear in the drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

i think that you could be persist the select value when the form is submitted in the "myForm" method. So, in the same method, retrieve the new group values. Try this:

```
function myform(){

    $data['title'] = "myform";
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('school_model');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
       $sdata['school'] = $this->input->post('school');
       $this->school_model->addItem($sdata);
    }

    $data['groups'] = $this->school_model->getAll();

    $this->load->view('myform', $data);
}
```

Comment: Are you using AJAX to submit the form ?

Comment: I'm not using ajax. I can now successfully add some data into the database, but my problem is that I cannot retrieve the data and display it in my drop down list.

Comment: In my example, before load the view, debug `$data['groups']` with `var_dump($data['groups']); die;` and post the output. With my code, the values are saved into database ?

Comment: It says 'NULL' when I use var_dump. With your code, the values cannot be saved into the database.

Comment: Do a var_dump & die of $this->input->post after submit.

Comment: This is what appears:  bool(false)

Comment: If `$this->input->post()` is FALSE, this means that your values has not been submitted